# How to update image using image url

Tags: spring, spring-boot, jpa, multipartform-data

I have method which is taking multipart image file,if i want to update same image then obviously i have to take image url as a input but i cant able to take the input as url since it is taking file format
my method:

````
           MediaType.APPLICATION_OCTET_STREAM_VALUE}, produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
   public ResponseEntity<ApiResponse> updatePersonalDataForUser(
           @RequestHeader("accessToken") @NotEmpty(message = "accessToken is mandatory") String bearer,
           @RequestHeader("mappingId") @NotEmpty(message = "mappingId is mandatory") String mappingId,
           @RequestPart("personalInfoObj") String personalInfoObj,
           @RequestPart(value = "profileImage") MultipartFile profileImage)
           throws IOException {

       jobPostController.userRoleAuthorization(mappingId);
       userController.oAuthByRedisAccessToken(bearer, mappingId);

       ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
       PersonalInfoResponse personalInfoConv = objectMapper.readValue(personalInfoObj, PersonalInfoResponse.class);
       return userController.updatePersonalData(mappingId, personalInfoConv, profileImage, Contants.UserRoleName);
   }```
````

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the Spring community project called [Spring Content](https://paulcwarren.github.io/spring-content/).

This project makes it easy to build contentful applications and services.  It has the same programming model as Spring Data.  Meaning it can supply implementations for the file storage and REST controllers on top of that file storage, therefore you don't need to concern yourself with creating these yourself.   It is to content (or unstructured data) what Spring Data is to structured data.

This might look something like the following:-

> pom.xml (for Spring Web MVC.  Spring Boot also supported)

```
   <!-- Spring Web MVC dependencies -->
   ...

   <!-- Java API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-fs</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.M5</version>
   </dependency>

   <!-- REST API -->
   <dependency>
      <groupId>com.github.paulcwarren</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-content-rest</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0.M5</version>
   </dependency>
```

> StoreConfig.java

```
@Configuration
@EnableFilesystemStores
@Import(RestConfiguration.class)
public class EnableFilesystemStoresConfig {

    @Bean
    File filesystemRoot() {
        try {
            return new File("/path/to/your/uploaded/files");
        } catch (IOException ioe) {}
        return null;
    }

    @Bean
    FileSystemResourceLoader fileSystemResourceLoader() {
        return new FileSystemResourceLoader(filesystemRoot().getAbsolutePath());
    }

}
```

> ImageStore.java

```
@StoreRestResource(path="images")
public interface ImageStore extends Store<String> {
}
```

This is all you need to do to get REST Endpoints that will allow you to store and retrieve files.  As mentioned how this actually works is very much like Spring Data.  When your application starts Spring Content will see the `spring-content-fs` dependency, know that you want to store content on your filesystem and inject a filesystem implementation of the `ImageStore` interface into the application context.  It will also see the `spring-content-rest` and inject a controller (i.e. REST endpoints) that talk to the `ImageStore` interface.  Therefore, you don't have to do any of this yourself.

So, for example:

`curl -X POST /images/myimage.jpg -F "file=@/path/to/myimage.jpg"`

will store the image on the filesystem at `/path/to/your/uploaded/files/myimage.jpg`

And:

`curl /images/myimage.jpg`

will fetch it again and so on...these endpoints support full CRUD and the GET & PUT endpoints also support video streaming (or byte range-requests).

You could also decide to store the contents elsewhere like in the database with your entities, or in S3 by swapping the `spring-content-fs` dependency for the appropriate Spring Content Storage module.  Examples for every type of storage are [here](https://github.com/paulcwarren/spring-content-examples).

In addition, in case it is helpful, often content is associated with Spring Data Entities.  So, it is also possible to have the ImageStore interface implement ContentStore, like this:

```
> FileStore.java

    @StoreRestResource(path="images")
    public interface ImageStore extends ContentStore<PersonalInfo, String> {
    }
```

And to add Spring Content-annotated fields to your Spring Data entities, like this:

```
> PersonalInfo.java

    @Entity
    public class PersonalInfo {
       @Id
       @GeneratedValue
       private long id;

       ...other existing fields...

       @ContentId
       private String contentId;

       @ContentLength
       private long contentLength = 0L;

       @MimeType
       private String mimeType = "text/plain";

       ...
    }
```

This approach changes the REST endpoints as the content is now addressable via the Spring Data URL.  So:

`POST /personalInfos/{personalInfoId} -F "image=@/some/path/to/myimage.jpg"`

will upload `myimage.jpg` to `/path/to/your/uploaded/files/myimage.jpg`.  As it did before but it will also update the fields on the PersonalInfo entity with id `personalInfoId`.

`GET /personalInfos/{personalInfoId}`

will get it again.

HTH